# magento Tax setup for the CANADA Quebec

Tags: magento-1.8, tax-class

We have 3 product Tax classes
TPS
TVQ
HST

We have 3 Tax Rules

```
Name         Customer Tax Class P.Tax classe    Tax Rate                priority subtotal only sort order

CAN-QC-GST   Retail Customer     TPS            CAN-QC-GST(5)                 0                1       0
CAN-QC-PST   Retail Customer     TVQ            CAN-QC-PST(9.75)                 1                1       1
CAN-QC-HST   Retail Customer     HST            CAN-QC-GST(5), CAN-QC-PST(9.975)     2                1       0
```

When the product belongs to HST class, I am getting only PST(9.75) tax rate in  cart. But I should get both tax rates.
Please help me with  my configuration!.

Comment: There's a pretty detailed document up at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-tax-config-ca

Comment: JasonS's link is dead, new link is https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/configuration-canada.html